# PHP Script to change the server time

Tags: php, server

I use HostGator for some clients websites and it's a shared cloud server setup. I need to run this script:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
?>
```

because the server time is setup to a time zone not anywhere close to the US.. How do I execute that script so the server time changes.. They don't support (HostGator) the changing of the server time but suggest running the above script.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Jason, you need to run [that command](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) on the script that's being executed, i.e., it needs to be in your '....php' file, as code.

Answer (score -1):

Servers, assuming they are running in geographically different parts of the world, will all have different datetimes, depending on their timezone. What happens when you migrate to a server residing in a different time zone? All of your datetimes will be shifted which can cause some pretty serious problems.

You may also run into scenarios where the application server (say, PHP) is running in one timezone, while the database server (say, PostgreSQL) is running in a separate time zone - What do you do then, where some datetimes may be generated by PHP, and others generated by PostgreSQL?

The answer is to factor in `timezones`.

Programming languages such as PHP and Python as well as databases such as MySQL and PostgreSQL all have the ability to work not only in rigid server-specific time, but also in more flexible, timezones.

In databases such as PostgreSQL, you can set the data type to `timestamp with time zone`.

In PHP, you can use timezones to fix the difference between the datetime the server displays by defaults, and what the user may be expecting.

Here's an example in PHP, which enables you to:

- Get the server's current datetime
- Convert the server's datetime to the timezone the user resides in
- Display the converted datetime to the user

```
<?php
// Set the user's timezone:
$user_timezone = 'America/Detroit';

// Get the current datetime
$datetime = new DateTime();

// Display the server's datetime in human-readable and UNIX timestamp formats
print(
    "\nServer's Datetime: " . $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "" .
    "\nServer's Timestamp: " . $datetime->getTimestamp() . "" .
);

// Instantiate a DateTimeZone object representing the user's timezone
$timezone = new DateTimeZone( $user_timezone );

// Set the timezone on that datetime to be the user's timezone
$datetime->setTimezone( $timezone );

// Display the converted datetime to the user in human-readable format:
print(
    "\nUser's Datetime: " . $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "" .
    "\nUsers's Timestamp: " . $datetime->getTimestamp() . "" .
);
?>
```

Disclaimer, I haven't tested any of the above code, only constructed from PHP references:

- Datetime Object: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
- DateTimeZone Object: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php
- Listing Timezones: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php

If you're not sure what `$user_timezone` should be set to, run this command in php and view the output:

```
<?php
print_r(
    timezone_identifiers_list()
);
>?>
```